# working mvc area

Tags: model-view-controller, area

I have a some problems working with Areas. I am using Ado.Net Entity frame work and I generated POCO for my Model in the default Model, Now that I have to work in my Area (Admin Area) I cannot access the POCO. I thought of regenerating another POCO in my admin Model Area but not sure if is a right thing to do since it will be duplication and my database object are quite much. Please respond?

Comment: What you are trying to do is perfectly reasonable.  You should certainly not need to use a separate Model for the area.  Have you any more details of the errors you are getting.  The obvious thing to check would be namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Areas are in reality just mini mvc structures (i.e. controllers, views, etc). If this has something to do with routing then make sure you are adding the correct namespaces to the DataTokens when calling MapRoute:

```
 .DataTokens.Add("namespaces", new string[] { "MyNamespace.MyControllers" });
```

Or make sure you are specifiing the area in your action calls.

Honestly though I am thinking this is more of you needing to add a using directive.

More information would be helpful please.

Comment: I guess I got confused at some point. I have resolved the issues. Thank you all